# weblogic jersey classloader update

Tags: java, jersey, weblogic, classloader

I'm getting the following error message when overriden weblogic's jersey (1.18) with my app jersey (1.19) in weblogic 12.1.3

```
Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.WebApplicationProviderImpl to com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationProvider"
```

I have the following jars in my project's war file:

1. jersey-bundle-1.19.jar
2. jersey-client-1.19.jar
3. jersey-core-1.19.jar
4. jersey-json-1.19.jar
5. jersey-server-1.19.jar
6. jersey-servlet-1.19.jar

It is a multiproject with several weblogic.xml files, and they look as the documentation describes for war files (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/version.htm#RESTF201):

```
<weblogic-web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"><session-descriptor>...</session-descriptor><container-descriptor>
    <prefer-application-packages>

        <!-- jersey-bundle-*.jar -->
        <package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</package-name>
        <package-name>jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.*</package-name>

        <!-- Jackson-*.jar -->
        <package-name>org.codehaus.jackson.*</package-name>

        <!-- jettison-*.jar -->
        <package-name>org.codehaus.jettison.*</package-name>

        <!-- jsr311*.jar -->
        <package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</package-name>

        <!-- asm.jar -->
        <package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</package-name>

    </prefer-application-packages>
</container-descriptor></weblogic-web-app>
```

I also tried adding

```
<prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
```

but is not working (same exception)...

Any thoughts on this??

Comment: may be the version of weblogic you're using? https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-8017

Comment: But I'm not using that OpenAM thing :(